# How to get access to the global variable inside a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I made a custom hook(useData) that takes `query` as an argument and then returns data and runtime(time to fetch the data from the API). But I need access to the runtime to my Editor component when I click on the run button. Right now what is happening is when I click on the run button(inside Editor.js), it sets the `query` to the App component using the setter function, and then it passes that query to the Table component and then calls the custom hook using that query and then table make use of that data. but I want the `runtime` in the Editor component, not in the Table component. I know I can call the `useData` hook in the Editor component but my editor component gets rerender every time when we write on the editor, so It calls the useData() hook on each change.

Any way to get the runtime without calling useData() on every change?

App.js code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./assets/output.css";
import Footer from "./components/layouts/Footer";
import Navbar from "./components/layouts/Navbar";
import Sidebar from "./components/layouts/Sidebar";
import TableSection from "./components/table/TableSection";
import Editor from "./components/editor/Editor";
const App = () => {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  const [value, setValue] = useState("select * from customers");

  return (
    <>
      <div className="grid grid-cols-layout-desktop grid-rows-layout-desktop bg-gray-600 h-screen">
        <Navbar />
        <Sidebar setQuery={setQuery} setValue={setValue} />
        <Editor setQuery={setQuery} value={value} setValue={setValue} />
        {query ? <TableSection query={query} /> : null}
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Editor.js

```
import React from "react";
import AceEditor from "react-ace";
import "ace-builds/src-min-noconflict/ext-language_tools";
import "ace-builds/src-min-noconflict/mode-mysql";
import "ace-builds/src-noconflict/theme-github";
import useData from "../../hooks/useData";

const Editor = ({ setQuery, value, setValue }) => {
  const { runtime } = useData();
  const onChange = (newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  const onSubmit = () => {
    var Z = value.toLowerCase().slice(value.indexOf("from") + "from".length);
    setQuery(Z.split(" ")[1]);
  };

  return (
    <div className="col-start-2 col-end-3 row-start-2 row-end-3 m-6">
      <AceEditor
        aria-label="query editor input"
        mode="mysql"
        theme="github"
        name={Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000).toString()}
        fontSize={16}
        minLines={15}
        maxLines={10}
        width="100%"
        showPrintMargin={false}
        showGutter
        placeholder="Write your Query here..."
        editorProps={{ $blockScrolling: true }}
        setOptions={{
          enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
          enableLiveAutocompletion: true,
          enableSnippets: true,
        }}
        value={value}
        onChange={onChange}
        showLineNumbers
      />
      <div className="">
        <button
          className="bg-white text-gray-800 rounded-md font-semibold px-4 py-2 my-4"
          onClick={onSubmit}
        >
          <i className="fas fa-play"></i> Run SQL
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Editor;
```

Hook code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import alasql from "alasql";
import toast from "react-hot-toast";
import TABLE_NAMES from "../utils/tableNames";

const getURL = (name) =>
  `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/graphql-compose/graphql-compose-examples/master/examples/northwind/data/csv/${name}.csv`;

const useData = (tableName) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [runtime, setRuntime] = useState("");
  const convertToJson = (data) => {
    alasql
      .promise("SELECT * FROM CSV(?, {headers: false, separator:','})", [data])
      .then((data) => {
        setData(data);
        toast.success("Query run successfully");
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        toast.error(e.message);
      });
  };
  const fetchData = (tableName) => {
    setData([]);
    const name = TABLE_NAMES.find((name) => name === tableName);
    if (name) {
      setError(false);
      fetch(getURL(tableName))
        .then((res) => res.text())
        .then((data) => convertToJson(data));
    } else {
      setError(true);
      toast.error("Please enter a valid query");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    let t0 = performance.now(); //start time
    fetchData(tableName);
    let t1 = performance.now(); //end time
    setRuntime(t1 - t0);
    console.log(
      "Time taken to execute add function:" + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds"
    );
  }, [tableName]);

  return { data, runtime, error };
};

export default useData;
```

Comment: can you show your code for the hook please

Comment: just added, please check

Comment: you should make your hook be a context that wraps your app using `useContext`

Comment: I don't know how to do that. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: If possible add it as an answer, so It would be helpful for other people.

Comment: To double-down on RichardHpa's comment, you will move the state and query logic from `useData` into a [React Context Propvider](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) and convert the `useData` hook to simply return the context value. You'll still need to use the `useData` hook anywhere you want to use the query logic, but now it'll be a single global value instead of each hook "instance" maintaining their own.

Comment: Hey @DrewReese Can you please make a code sandbox of what you have said if possible that will be really helpful? Thanks in advance

Comment: I am completely stuck at this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Actually, I see that you have a sort of dependency on `tableName` for fetching specific data. Instead of rolling your own solution have you looked into existing libraries that help in this area, like [react-query](https://react-query.tanstack.com/) or [RTK-query](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/overview)? They help manage multiple queries and cache results.

Comment: Also, SO isn't so much about being a code writing service, it's more for helping with specific issues with existing code.

Comment: Can you please show me a roadmap to achieve that functionality?

Comment: have a read through the article that Drew posted, it's a good description about it. Then give it a go and if you can't get it then show us what you have done and then we can help more. Like he said this isnt a free code writing service.

Comment: Ok! will go through the article. Thanks

Comment: but he posted the link of the libraries

Comment: Is their any blog related to this?